# Check if user signin with gmail for first time

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

Hi I want to check if user who sign in to my application is the first time or not with

```
task.getResult().getAdditionalUserInfo().isNewUser()
```

but if always return false even I use an account that never sign in to my account.

These are some pieces of my code.

```
private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount account) {
    Log.d(TAG, "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + account.getId());

    AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(account.getIdToken(), null);
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                        isNew = task.getResult().getAdditionalUserInfo().isNewUser();
                        Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success");
                        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                        //updateUI(user);
                    } else {
                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                        Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                        Toast.makeText( NewLoginActivity.this, "Authentication Failed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        //updateUI(null);
                    }


                }
            });
}
```

I want to check if user is ever sign in or not because if user never sign in to my app i want user to fill some information.

```
mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(isNew));
            if ( mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null && isNew ){         // New User
                Log.d(TAG, "New User");
                startActivity( new Intent(NewLoginActivity.this, NewRegisterForSocialActivity.class) );
            }
            else if ( mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null && !isNew ) {  // Old User
                startActivity( new Intent(NewLoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class) );
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: If your end goal is to make sure that a user fills out some information, it could be easier to just check your database for whether or not the extra user information exists or for a generic boolean set to true if it does exist.

Comment: Thank so much, I already think of that way but I think use .getAdditionalUserInfo().isNewUser(); is better because it is method that make for check if user sign in first time or not.